# Helm not using values override?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using sub-charts. Here's my directory structure

```
/path/microservice-base-chart
/path/myApp
```

I have this `values.yaml` for my "base" (generic) chart

```yaml
# Default region and repository
aws_region: us-east-1
repository: 012234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

repositories:
  us-east-1: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  eu-north-1: 98765432109.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com

image:
  name: ""
  version: ""
```

...and this in the base chart's `templates/_helpers.yaml` file

```yaml
{{/*
Get the repository from the AWS region
*/}}
{{- define "microservice-base-chart.reponame" -}}
{{- $repo := index .Values.repositories .Values.aws_region | default .Values.repository }}
{{- printf "%s" $repo }}
{{- end }}
```

...and this in the base chart's `templates/deployment.yaml` file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
    ...
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.image.name }}
        image: {{ include "microservice-base-chart.reponame" . }}/{{ .Values.image.name }}:{{ .Values.image.version }}
```

I have this in the `Chart.yaml` of a sub chart that uses the base chart.

```yaml
dependencies:
  - alias: microservice-0
    name: microservice-base-chart
    version: "0.1.0"
    repository: file://../microservice-base-chart
```

...and this in the `values.yaml` of a sub chart

```yaml
microservice-0:
  image:
    name: myApp
    version: 1.2.3
```

However, when I run this, where I set `aws_region`

```
$ helm install marcom-stats-svc microservice-chart/  \
    --set image.aws_region=eu-north-1 \
    --set microservice-0.image.version=2.0.0 \
    --dry-run --debug
```

I get this for the image name of the above `deployment.yaml` template

```yaml
image: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myApp:2.0.0
```

instead of the expected

```yaml
image: 98765432109.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/myApp:2.0.0
```

What am I missing? TIA

Comment: Can you put a directory tree to understand how files and charts are organized?

Comment: I think you are overriding the wrong value, try `--set microservice-0.aws_region=eu-north-1` instead of `--set image.aws_region=eu-north-1`

Comment: @MarcosToledo, that was it, and it totally makes sense. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!